# Finding the % of missing values from the entire dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

The shape of my dataset is (130,20) which can be found using the `df.shape` command of python. I also found out the total number of missing values in the data set using `df.isnull().sum().sum()` command.

Now I want to know the % of missing values in the dataset.

Total value 130*20 = 2600

total missing values = 850

% of missing values (850/2600)*100 = 32.69%

I am not sure my method is alright for fining % of missing values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do

```
df.isna().to_numpy().ravel().mean()
```

Or

```
df.isna().mean().mean()
```

Comment: I did not understand why should I find the mean of null values? Mean is nothing but the average. mean = sum of terms/number of terms. How could it be related to finding the % of null values?

Comment: @Encipher isna return True for NaN and False for not NaN, which is 1 and 0 , if you would like get the percentage of 1 , you do sum([1, 0 ]) /2  = mean([1,0])